# How can I print only the division that i want on html?

Tags: php, html, css

Hi guys I want that on the print section only the this division will be shown,
what would be the script to this? And by the way this is a modal of every tenant on a table. This print will serve as a receipt of every tenant.

```
            <div class="modal-body">
            <form  class="form-horizontal" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>
                        <div>
                            <h3 class="modal-title text-center" id="myModalLabel">
                            <strong>Republic of the Philippines<br>Province of Negros Occidental</strong></h3>
                            <h4 class ="text-center"><em>City of Victorias</em></h4>
                            <h4 class="text-center">
                                <strong>OFFICE OF THE MARKET SUPERVISOR</strong>
                            </h4>

                            <br>                            
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type = "hidden" class="form-control" name= "id" placeholder="First Name" value = "<?php echo $value['rate_id'];?>">  
                                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name </label>: <?php echo $value['tenant_fname']." ".$value['tenant_mname']." ".$value['tenant_lname'];?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Location </label>: Stall No. <?php echo $value['stall_number']." (".$value['stall_floor'];?>)
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">SUBJECT </label> :
                                FOR PAYMENT OF ELECTRICAL CONSUMPTION FOR THE &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;PERIOD FROM
                                <input class = "datepick custom-input1"></input>
                                ,TO 
                                <input class = "datepick custom-input1"></input>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">METER NO. </label>: <input type="text" name=""  class = "custom-input"></input> 
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">ELECTRIC RATE </label>: <input class = "custom-input"  value="<?php echo $value['elec_rate']?> per kWh" id= "rate" readonly ></input> 
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">PRESENT </label>: <input class = "custom-input" id="current" name="current"></input> 
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">PREVIOUS </label>: <input  class = "custom-input" value ="<?php echo $value['charges']?> kWh" id = "previous" readonly> </input> 
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">TOTAL CONSUMPTION</label>:
                                <input type="text"  class = "custom-input" type="" id="result1" readonly> 
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">AMOUNT </label>:
                                <input type="text"  class = "custom-input" type="" id="result" readonly>                                    
                            </div><br>                              
                        </strong>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Can you share what you've tried?

Comment: i cant comment what I have tried. cause its to long
I have tried a javascript code and it didn't go well.

Comment: Add what you have tried to your question because if you don't your question will end up being closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not wrong, then the code below will do what you want. For more information, refer to the [MDN documentation about @media](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media).

```
@media print {
    body * { 
        visibility: hidden; 
    }
    .modal-body* { 
        visibility: visible; 
    }
    .modal-body{ 
        display: block!important; 
        position: absolute; 
        top: 40px; 
        left: 30px; 
    }
}
```

Comment: sir will the media print work on this code? 
<button onclick="myFunction()">Print this page</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    window.print();
}
</script>

Comment: you need to tweak the code little bit based on ur need but idea will be same

Comment: I already got what i want in mind sir, thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

There is a [media query for printing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media).

```
@media print {
    /*your printing specific css here*/
}
```